# pagination with numbers for WP_User_Query

Tags: wp-query, pagination, wp-user-query

I have pagination with next/previous links but I also would like to show numbers so the user can click on 2, 3, 4 etc. Pagination seems more tricky with WP_User_Query as there isn't any default WordPress pagination for this as far as I know. The below works correctly as far as I can tell for the next and previous links.

```
$current_page = get_query_var('paged') ? (int) get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$users_per_page = 2;

$args = array(
    'number' => $users_per_page, 
    'paged' => $current_page
);

$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

$total_users = $wp_user_query->get_total();
$num_pages = ceil($total_users / $users_per_page);

       <?php
        // Previous page
        if ( $current_page > 1 ) {
            echo '<a href="'. add_query_arg(array('paged' => $current_page-1)) .'" class="prev">Prev</a>';
        }

        // Next page
        if ( $current_page < $num_pages ) {
            echo '<a href="'. add_query_arg(array('paged' => $current_page+1)) .'" class="next">Next</a>';
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/):

```php
echo paginate_links( array(
  'current' => $current_page,
  'total'   => $num_pages,
) );
```

Comment: Sally CJ, you are a legend!

Answer (score -1):

Please try below function for numeric pagination and change query variable as per your requirement.

```
function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this only works on archive pages apparently. I am not using an archive page.